# Format certain rows where a cell value meets a condition when exporting from VB.NET (DataGridView) to Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, formatting, export

I am new to VB syntax, and im struggling with adding conditions to an excel export.
I have a dataset (ds2) that populates a DataGridView (dgvBreaks).The data in the dataset will look something like this:

| Emp_Name | ClockDate | Time_In | Time_Out | Total_Hours | Actual_Hours | Breaks | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Moloto, Joseph | 04/04/2022 00:00 | 07:36:00 | 06:42:00 | 5,8 | 4,60 | 2 | Clocked out on: 2022-04-05 - |
| Moloto, Joseph | 04/05/2022 00:00 | 07:22:00 | 07:22:00 | 9,2 | 9,00 | 1 |  |
| Moloto, Joseph | 04/06/2022 00:00 | 07:40:00 | 16:31:00 | 8,9 | 8,80 | 0 |  |
| Moloto, Joseph | 04/07/2022 00:00 | 07:25:00 | 16:29:00 | 9,1 | 9,00 | 0 |  |
| Moloto, Joseph | 04/08/2022 00:00 | 07:34:00 | 15:35:00 | 8,0 | 8,90 | 0 |  |
| Moloto, Joseph | 04/11/2022 00:00 | 07:42:00 | 16:33:00 | 8,9 | 8,80 | 0 |  |

I want to export the data from the gridview or dataset to excel and format certain rows based on a cell value. FOR EXAMPLE: Highlight a row in red if the Actual hours is less than 8. so that this row would be in red:

| Emp_Name | ClockDate | Time_In | Time_Out | Total_Hours | Actual_Hours | Breaks | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Moloto, Joseph | 04/04/2022 00:00 | 07:36:00 | 06:42:00 | 5,8 | 4,60 | 2 | Clocked out on: 2022-04-05 - |

Currently I export the data to an excel sheet using the code below:

```
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
    For i = 0 To dgvDataBreaks.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To dgvDataBreaks.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To dgvDataBreaks.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = dgvDataBreaks.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvDataBreaks(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    Next
    Dim path As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
    path.ShowDialog()
    If DialogResult.OK Then
        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(path.FileName)
    End If
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    MsgBox("You can find the file at: " + path.FileName)
```

But I am not sure how to add the conditional check. (How would I check only the 'Actual Hours' for instace?)

Comment: _”But I am not sure where to add my condition”_ … You should put the “condition check” at the start or end of each row. Also, to simplify things, I suggest you drop the third inner `k` loop. If you trace the code, you will see that it writes the header cells to the work sheet over and over. I suggest you write the headers FIRST in its own loop before you start looping through the data. In other words, drop the `k` loop as it is unnecessary and only complicates things.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldve phrased that properly, I understand that it must be in the loop, so as to check all values 1 by 1, but where exactly? how would i specify that it should check the value of the 'Actual Hours' Column for instance and what syntax would I use to do so?

Comment: Well… look at the first `for` loop… `For i = 0 To dgvDataBreaks.RowCount – 2` … that loops through all the rows. Before you start the second `for` loop through the columns… check what value in the Actual Hours cell is and color that row accordingly. Coloring the row in Excel may look something like… `xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, 1), xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, 8)).Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red)`.

Comment: Thank you, I did something similar to this just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JohnG stated in the comments, it is quite simple:

```
xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, 1), xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, 8)).Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red)
```